# Adding Bulk Inserting to Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, async-await

We have an API that companies use to add products to our catalog system.

The issue is that currently it is a 1 item at a time setup, which to a vendor that will input 10-20k entries at a time, is a massive pain.

I'm looking to add a bulk option to the api but unsure how to add synch support to this.

I'm using MVC 5 & Web API 2 and .NET 4.5

Everything I find on this is talking about uploading not bulk inserting records.

EDIT:

I should add that the user would be chunking the data to 20-50 records at a time.

Comment: Personally, I would go the route of adding file processing to your api. After you go through the trouble of coding the processing 20/50 items at a time using a POST with a List<Product> or Product[] your client is then limited to pumping small segments to your api when they could have batched it all up and sent it at once.

Comment: the issue is their bulk file they give us has a lot of data we have to sort and scrub first, so that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably finding those references to uploads due to the fact that the best way to handle what you describe is to provide functionality to upload a file of products and then process the file server side.

If you add a method to accept a blob of 20k entries in your api then you will have to set your max http request/json size to an astronomical number. Not to mention it is a daunting task to provide feedback to the client while the data is being transferred.

By using an async file upload you can provide file transfer progress to the user and the whole process will be less error prone. You can break the processing into chunks.

Bulk insert/copy is more of a database term that describes a more efficient way to upload large data into a database.

Comment: the idea would be that the user would chunk up their data and insert 20-50 at a time.

Comment: I suggest that you update your question to reflect that condition.